# Upload CSV with UTF-8 Characters to Server

Tags: c#, csv, file-upload, utf-8

I'm able to upload CSV content from browser to the server, however non-ASCII characters like "š" in the string "Pštrossova" come out like "P�trossova" when I parse the contents on the server.

I'm processing the file as follows hoping to preserve UTF8 encoding, but it's not working (result contains "P�trossova" but I want "Pštrossova")

```
// Read bytes from http input stream
        BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["file"].InputStream);
        byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes( Convert.ToInt32(Request.Files["file"].InputStream.Length) );
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData);
```